# how to get product attribute(all) in "catalog_product" collection?

Tags: magento, collections, magento-1.7, magento-1.6, meta-key

i want to get all attribute of the product in the product collection.

i've try this

```
$samp_pro = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1223)->getData();
```

it'll load attribute **meta keyword**.

But when i load it in collection ,doesn't get the **meta keyword** attribute,
the code is

```
$products1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addFieldToFilter('meta_keyword', array('like' => '%'.$metaData.'%'))
                 ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
                 ->getData();
```

I need to load **meta keyword** attribute in collection,help me to fix this issue

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you will try this below code:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

    $sql        = "SELECT * FROM <table-prefix>_catalog_product_entity_text WHERE attribute_id=(SELECT attribute_id FROM <table-prefix>_eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code='meta_keyword') AND value LIKE '%$metaData%'";

    $products1       =$connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it in manually:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('meta_keyword')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this on my own system and the meta_keyword field did come through.

One difference, however, is that in the first example you are loading the model whereas in the second example you are loading a collection.  As such there is a huge difference in the SQL that is being executed.

Comment: thanks kevin,
how can i get the "meta keyword" attribute in product collocation?